# How to place a section of an input library into a special section of output ELF file while using lld?

Tags: c, clang, linker-scripts

I'm using clang for some bare-metal developing. It worked pretty good, until when I want to put the '.text' section from a static library, called 'libfw.a' here, into a special section, called '.sys_text', of the output image, but the it(the '.text' section of libfw.a) NEVER goes into '.sys_text' section.

It's pretty strange, because when I use arm-none-eabi-gcc with same linker script, everything is OK. I'm wondering if there is something different about linker script between clang and gcc?

I'm using clang 8.0.1, arm-none-eabi-gcc 9.2.0.

[This project can be found in github](https://github.com/lixingangsms/stm32f407_template.git)

There is related part of linker script:

```
  .sys_text : ALIGN(4)
  {
    fw/libfw.a:(.text .text.*)
  } >FLASH
```

and this is whole script about output sections:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
  .isr_vector : ALIGN(4)
  {
    FILL(0xFF)
    KEEP(*(.vector))
    *(.fast_call .fast_call.*)
  } >FLASH

  .sys_inits : ALIGN(4)
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__hwinit_early_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.hwinit_early_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.hwinit_early_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__hwinit_early_array_end = .);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__hwinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.hwinit_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.hwinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__hwinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  .sys_text : ALIGN(4)
  {
    libst.a:(.text .text.*)
  } >FLASH

  .inits : ALIGN(4)
  {
    __data_regions_array_start = .;
    LONG(LOADADDR(.data));
    LONG(ADDR(.data));
    LONG(ADDR(.data)+SIZEOF(.data));
    __data_regions_array_end = .;

    __bss_regions_array_start = .;
    LONG(ADDR(.bss));
    LONG(ADDR(.bss)+SIZEOF(.bss));
    __bss_regions_array_end = .;

    KEEP(*(.init))
    KEEP(*(.fini))

    PROVIDE_HIDDEN(__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(.preinit_array .preinit_array.*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);

    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);

    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.fini_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  .text : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.text .text.*)

    *(.rodata .rodata.* .constdata .constdata.*)

    *(vtable)

    KEEP(*(.eh_frame*))

    *(.glue_7)
    *(.glue_7t)

  } >FLASH


  .ARM.extab : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  } >FLASH

  __exidx_start = .;    
  .ARM.exidx : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
  } > FLASH
  __exidx_end = .;

  .data : ALIGN(4)
  {
    FILL(0xFF)

    *(.data .data.*)

  } >RAM AT>FLASH

  .bss (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.bss .bss.*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
  } >RAM

  ._check_heap(NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
  {
    . = . + _minimum_heap_size ;
  } >RAM

  /DISCARD/ :
  {
  }
}
```

follows are map files.
this is related part in map file of clang, we can see fw/libfw.a's all `.text` is in `.text` section rather than `.sys_text` section specified in linker script.

```
80001f8  80001f8      424     4 .text
 80001f8  80001f8       4c     2         src/CMakeFiles/template.dir/main.c.obj:(.text.main)
 80001f8  80001f8        0     1                 $t.0
 80001f9  80001f9       4c     1                 main
 8000244  8000244       76     2         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.text.SystemInit)
 8000244  8000244        0     1                 $t.0
 8000245  8000245       76     1                 SystemInit
 80002ba  80002ba      136     2         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.text.SetSysClock)
 80002ba  80002ba        0     1                 $t.1
 80002bb  80002bb      136     1                 SetSysClock
 80003f0  80003f0      134     2         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.text.SystemCoreClockUpdate)
 80003f0  80003f0        0     1                 $t.2
 80003f1  80003f1      134     1                 SystemCoreClockUpdate
 8000524  8000524       4c     2         rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj):(.text._os_start)
 8000524  8000524        0     1                 $t.1
 8000525  8000525       4c     1                 _os_start
 8000570  8000570       90     2         rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj):(.text._libc_start)
 8000570  8000570        0     1                 $t.2
 8000571  8000571       90     1                 _libc_start
 8000600  8000600        c     2         rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj):(.text._exit)
 8000600  8000600        0     1                 $t.3
 8000601  8000601        c     1                 _exit
 800060c  800060c       10     1         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.rodata.AHBPrescTable)
 800060c  800060c       10     1                 AHBPrescTable
 800061c  800061c        0     1 __exidx_start = .
 800061c  800061c       10     4 .ARM.exidx
 800061c  800061c        8     4         fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj):(.ARM.exidx.fast_call)
 8000624  8000624        8     4         <internal>:(.ARM.exidx)
 800062c  800062c        0     1 __exidx_end = .
```

whole map file:

```
     VMA      LMA     Size Align Out     In      Symbol
       0        0        0     1 _eheap = ORIGIN ( RAM ) + LENGTH ( RAM )
       0        0        0     1 _stack = ORIGIN ( CCMRAM ) + LENGTH ( CCMRAM )
       0        0        0     1 _minimum_heap_size = 256
 8000000  8000000      1dc     4 .isr_vector
 8000000  8000000      188     4         fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj):(.vector)
 8000000  8000000      188     1                 irq_vector
 8000188  8000188        8     2         fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj):(.fast_call)
 8000188  8000188        0     1                 $t.0
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 ADC_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 BusFault_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN1_TX_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN2_RX1_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN2_SCE_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CAN2_TX_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 CRYP_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DCMI_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream1_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA1_Stream7_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream1_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream4_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream6_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 DebugMon_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 Defaut_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 ETH_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 ETH_WKUP_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 EXTI0_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 EXTI15_10_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 EXTI1_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 EXTI2_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 EXTI3_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 EXTI4_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 EXTI9_5_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 FLASH_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 FPU_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 FSMC_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 HASH_RNG_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 HardFault_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 I2C1_ER_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 I2C1_EV_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 I2C2_ER_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 I2C2_EV_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 I2C3_ER_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 I2C3_EV_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 MemManage_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 NMI_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 OTG_FS_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 OTG_HS_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 PVD_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 PendSV_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 RCC_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 SDIO_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 SPI1_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 SPI2_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 SPI3_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 SVC_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 SysTick_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM2_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM3_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM4_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM5_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM7_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM8_CC_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 UART4_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 UART5_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 USART1_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 USART2_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 USART3_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 USART6_IRQHandler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 UsageFault_Handler
 8000189  8000189        8     1                 WWDG_IRQHandler
 8000190  8000190       4c     2         rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj):(.fast_call)
 8000190  8000190        0     1                 $t.0
 8000191  8000191       4c     1                 _start
 80001dc  80001dc        8     4 .sys_inits
 80001dc  80001dc        0     1         PROVIDE_HIDDEN ( __hwinit_early_array_start = . )
 80001dc  80001dc        4     4         fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj):(.hwinit_early_array)
 80001dc  80001dc        4     1                 __export_hwinit_early_array_0_SystemInit
 80001e0  80001e0        0     1         PROVIDE_HIDDEN ( __hwinit_early_array_end = . )
 80001e0  80001e0        0     1         PROVIDE_HIDDEN ( __hwinit_array_start = . )
 80001e0  80001e0        4     4         fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj):(.hwinit_array)
 80001e0  80001e0        4     1                 __export_hwinit_array_0_SystemCoreClockUpdate
 80001e4  80001e4        0     1         PROVIDE_HIDDEN ( __hwinit_array_end = . )
 80001e4  80001e4       14     4 .inits
 80001e4  80001e4        0     1         __data_regions_array_start = .
 80001e4  80001e4        4     1         LONG ( LOADADDR ( .data ) )
 80001e8  80001e8        4     1         LONG ( ADDR ( .data ) )
 80001ec  80001ec        4     1         LONG ( ADDR ( .data ) + SIZEOF ( .data ) )
 80001f0  80001f0        0     1         __data_regions_array_end = .
 80001f0  80001f0        0     1         __bss_regions_array_start = .
 80001f0  80001f0        4     1         LONG ( ADDR ( .bss ) )
 80001f4  80001f4        4     1         LONG ( ADDR ( .bss ) + SIZEOF ( .bss ) )
 80001f8  80001f8        0     1         __bss_regions_array_end = .
 80001f8  80001f8      424     4 .text
 80001f8  80001f8       4c     2         src/CMakeFiles/template.dir/main.c.obj:(.text.main)
 80001f8  80001f8        0     1                 $t.0
 80001f9  80001f9       4c     1                 main
 8000244  8000244       76     2         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.text.SystemInit)
 8000244  8000244        0     1                 $t.0
 8000245  8000245       76     1                 SystemInit
 80002ba  80002ba      136     2         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.text.SetSysClock)
 80002ba  80002ba        0     1                 $t.1
 80002bb  80002bb      136     1                 SetSysClock
 80003f0  80003f0      134     2         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.text.SystemCoreClockUpdate)
 80003f0  80003f0        0     1                 $t.2
 80003f1  80003f1      134     1                 SystemCoreClockUpdate
 8000524  8000524       4c     2         rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj):(.text._os_start)
 8000524  8000524        0     1                 $t.1
 8000525  8000525       4c     1                 _os_start
 8000570  8000570       90     2         rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj):(.text._libc_start)
 8000570  8000570        0     1                 $t.2
 8000571  8000571       90     1                 _libc_start
 8000600  8000600        c     2         rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj):(.text._exit)
 8000600  8000600        0     1                 $t.3
 8000601  8000601        c     1                 _exit
 800060c  800060c       10     1         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.rodata.AHBPrescTable)
 800060c  800060c       10     1                 AHBPrescTable
 800061c  800061c        0     1 __exidx_start = .
 800061c  800061c       10     4 .ARM.exidx
 800061c  800061c        8     4         fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj):(.ARM.exidx.fast_call)
 8000624  8000624        8     4         <internal>:(.ARM.exidx)
 800062c  800062c        0     1 __exidx_end = .
20000000  800062c        4     4 .data
20000000  800062c        4     4         fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj):(.data.SystemCoreClock)
20000000  800062c        4     1                 SystemCoreClock
20000004 20000004        0     4 .bss
20000004 20000004        0     1         . = ALIGN ( 4 )
20000004 20000004        0     1         _ebss = .
20000004 20000004      100     4 ._check_heap
20000004 20000004      100     1         . = . + _minimum_heap_size
```

this is related part in map file of gcc, we can see fw/libfw.a's all `.text` is in `.sys_text` section now.

```
.sys_text       0x00000000080001e0      0x268
 fw/libfw.a:(.text .text.*)
 .text.SystemInit
                0x00000000080001e0       0x6c fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)
                0x00000000080001e0                SystemInit
 .text.SystemCoreClockUpdate
                0x000000000800024c      0x104 fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)
                0x000000000800024c                SystemCoreClockUpdate
 .text.SetSysClock
                0x0000000008000350       0xf8 fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)
```

whole map file:

```
Linker script and memory map

.isr_vector     0x0000000008000000      0x1d8
 FILL mask 0xff
 *(.vector)
 .vector        0x0000000008000000      0x188 fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj)
 *(.fast_call .fast_call.*)
 .fast_call     0x0000000008000188        0xa fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj)
                0x0000000008000188                RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                HASH_RNG_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                EXTI2_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM8_CC_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DebugMon_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                HardFault_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                SysTick_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                PVD_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                SDIO_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                PendSV_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                NMI_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN2_RX1_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                EXTI3_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                I2C3_ER_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                EXTI0_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                I2C2_EV_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                FPU_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                UsageFault_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN2_SCE_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                SPI1_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DCMI_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                USART6_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                USART3_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                CRYP_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                UART5_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM4_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                I2C1_EV_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream1_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                UART4_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM3_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                RCC_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                EXTI15_10_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                ADC_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream7_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM7_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN2_TX_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM5_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                I2C3_EV_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                EXTI9_5_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                ETH_WKUP_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                SPI2_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                MemManage_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN1_TX_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                SVC_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                EXTI4_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                FSMC_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                ETH_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                WWDG_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM2_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                OTG_HS_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                EXTI1_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                Defaut_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                USART2_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                I2C2_ER_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream1_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                FLASH_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream4_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                BusFault_Handler
                0x0000000008000188                USART1_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                OTG_FS_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                SPI3_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                I2C1_ER_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA2_Stream6_IRQHandler
                0x0000000008000188                DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler
 *fill*         0x0000000008000192        0x2 ff
 .fast_call     0x0000000008000194       0x44 rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj)
                0x0000000008000194                _start

.sys_inits      0x00000000080001d8        0x8
                0x00000000080001d8                PROVIDE (__hwinit_early_array_start = .)
 *(SORT_BY_NAME(.hwinit_early_array.*))
 *(.hwinit_early_array*)
 .hwinit_early_array
                0x00000000080001d8        0x4 fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj)
                0x00000000080001dc                PROVIDE (__hwinit_early_array_end = .)
                0x00000000080001dc                PROVIDE (__hwinit_array_start = .)
 *(SORT_BY_NAME(.hwinit_array.*))
 *(.hwinit_array*)
 .hwinit_array  0x00000000080001dc        0x4 fw/libfw.a(startup_stm32f40_41xx.c.obj)
                0x00000000080001e0                PROVIDE (__hwinit_array_end = .)

.sys_text       0x00000000080001e0      0x268
 fw/libfw.a:(.text .text.*)
 .text.SystemInit
                0x00000000080001e0       0x6c fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)
                0x00000000080001e0                SystemInit
 .text.SystemCoreClockUpdate
                0x000000000800024c      0x104 fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)
                0x000000000800024c                SystemCoreClockUpdate
 .text.SetSysClock
                0x0000000008000350       0xf8 fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)

.inits          0x0000000008000448       0x14
                0x0000000008000448                __data_regions_array_start = .
                0x0000000008000448        0x4 LONG 0x800057c LOADADDR (.data)
                0x000000000800044c        0x4 LONG 0x20000000 ADDR (.data)
                0x0000000008000450        0x4 LONG 0x20000014 (ADDR (.data) + SIZEOF (.data))
                0x0000000008000454                __data_regions_array_end = .
                0x0000000008000454                __bss_regions_array_start = .
                0x0000000008000454        0x4 LONG 0x20000014 ADDR (.bss)
                0x0000000008000458        0x4 LONG 0x20000014 (ADDR (.bss) + SIZEOF (.bss))
                0x000000000800045c                __bss_regions_array_end = .
 *(.init)
 *(.fini)
                [!provide]                        PROVIDE (__preinit_array_start = .)
 *(.preinit_array .preinit_array.*)
                [!provide]                        PROVIDE (__preinit_array_end = .)
                [!provide]                        PROVIDE (__init_array_start = .)
 *(SORT_BY_NAME(.init_array.*))
 *(.init_array*)
                [!provide]                        PROVIDE (__init_array_end = .)
                [!provide]                        PROVIDE (__fini_array_start = .)
 *(SORT_BY_NAME(.fini_array.*))
 *(.fini_array)
                [!provide]                        PROVIDE (__fini_array_end = .)

.text           0x000000000800045c      0x11e
 *(.text .text.*)
 .text.main     0x000000000800045c       0x42 src/CMakeFiles/template.dir/main.c.obj
                0x000000000800045c                main
 *fill*         0x000000000800049e        0x2 
 .text._os_start
                0x00000000080004a0       0x44 rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj)
                0x00000000080004a0                _os_start
 .text._libc_start
                0x00000000080004e4       0x8c rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj)
                0x00000000080004e4                _libc_start
 .text._exit    0x0000000008000570        0xa rt/librt.a(_start.c.obj)
                0x0000000008000570                _exit
 *(.rodata .rodata.* .constdata .constdata.*)
 *(vtable)
 *(.eh_frame*)
 *(.glue_7)
 .glue_7        0x000000000800057a        0x0 linker stubs
 *(.glue_7t)
 .glue_7t       0x000000000800057a        0x0 linker stubs

.vfp11_veneer   0x000000000800057c        0x0
 .vfp11_veneer  0x000000000800057c        0x0 linker stubs

.v4_bx          0x000000000800057c        0x0
 .v4_bx         0x000000000800057c        0x0 linker stubs

.iplt           0x000000000800057c        0x0
 .iplt          0x000000000800057c        0x0 src/CMakeFiles/template.dir/main.c.obj

.rel.dyn        0x000000000800057c        0x0
 .rel.iplt      0x000000000800057c        0x0 src/CMakeFiles/template.dir/main.c.obj

.ARM.extab
 *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
                0x000000000800057a                __exidx_start = .

.ARM.exidx
 *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
                0x000000000800057a                __exidx_end = .

.data           0x0000000020000000       0x14 load address 0x000000000800057c
 FILL mask 0xff
 *(.data .data.*)
 .data.SystemCoreClock
                0x0000000020000000        0x4 fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)
                0x0000000020000000                SystemCoreClock
 .data.AHBPrescTable
                0x0000000020000004       0x10 fw/libfw.a(system_stm32f4xx.c.obj)
                0x0000000020000004                AHBPrescTable

.igot.plt       0x0000000020000014        0x0 load address 0x0000000008000590
 .igot.plt      0x0000000020000014        0x0 src/CMakeFiles/template.dir/main.c.obj

.bss            0x0000000020000014        0x0 load address 0x0000000008000590
 *(.bss .bss.*)
 *(COMMON)
                0x0000000020000014                . = ALIGN (0x4)
                0x0000000020000014                _ebss = .

._check_heap    0x0000000020000014      0x100 load address 0x0000000008000590
                0x0000000020000114                . = (. + _minimum_heap_size)
 *fill*         0x0000000020000014      0x100
```

Comment: I would probably say "while using `ld`" (the linker) since you're writing a linker script. That's not the job of `clang`. Both `gcc` and `clang` invoke `ld` to link files after compiling them and the linker script is used by `ld`. See `man ld`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but ```clang``` use ```lld``` while here ```gcc``` use ```ld```. The problem is, when I use this script with ```gcc```, it worked fine, while using ```clang```, the library DO NOT in the section I want put it in. I'm wondering what should I do to make it, or just ```clang```(or ```lld```) DO NOT support this feature.

Comment: Interesting, you should better explain the differences in the result between the two invocations. Adding the full command line used could help, and also running gcc verbose with `-v` could help too.

Comment: OK, now I update my question and add the map files of clang and gcc. Is that clear enough? I have to delete some lines in the map file , but I think the rest can clearly explain the problem.